# C# Custom Message Box that Returns Value OK or Cancel

Tags: c#, winforms

Because I want a nicer looking message box that actually appears where I want it to appear, I have to make my own custom message box.

How do I make one that returns a value?

The built in MessageBox.Show can return a DialogResult. I'm guessing I create something like that DialogResult class or can I use that class?

Comment: any form you make (pretty much) can return that value from a method. You can look into extending the normal messagebox if you like most of the behavior (I didn't check if it's sealed), or just make your own form and return DialogResult from a Show method you write yourself.

Comment: Using a form and making your own like @Nikki9696 suggested is extremely easy. I'd recommend that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate James' answer, however I wanted to post an answer that provides the full result of what I did to solve this problem to create a more functional custom message box tool.

See the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MyProgram
{
    class CustomMessageBox
    {
        Label txtMsg = new Label();
        Button btnOK = new Button();
        Button btnCancel = new Button();
        Form newForm = new Form();

        private DialogResult spawnForm(string title, string text, MessageBoxButtons type)
        {            
            if(type == MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
            {
                newForm.Text = title;
                newForm.Controls.Add(txtMsg);
                txtMsg.AutoSize = true;
                txtMsg.Text = text;
                newForm.Width = txtMsg.Width + 125;
                newForm.Height = txtMsg.Height + 125;
                newForm.MaximumSize = new Size(newForm.Width, newForm.Height);
                newForm.MinimumSize = new Size(newForm.Width, newForm.Height);
                txtMsg.Location = new Point(newForm.Width / 2 - txtMsg.Width / 2, newForm.Height / 2 - 40);
                newForm.Controls.Add(btnOK);
                newForm.Controls.Add(btnCancel);
                btnOK.Text = "OK";
                btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";

                btnOK.Location = new Point(newForm.Width / 2 - btnOK.Width / 2 - 60, txtMsg.Location.Y + txtMsg.Height + 20);
                btnCancel.Location = new Point(newForm.Width / 2 - btnOK.Width / 2 + 40, btnOK.Location.Y);
                btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                btnCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                newForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                return newForm.ShowDialog();
            } else
            {                
                newForm.Text = title;
                newForm.Controls.Add(txtMsg);
                txtMsg.AutoSize = true;
                txtMsg.Text = text;
                newForm.Width = txtMsg.Width + 125;
                newForm.Height = txtMsg.Height + 125;
                newForm.MaximumSize = new Size(newForm.Width, newForm.Height);
                newForm.MinimumSize = new Size(newForm.Width, newForm.Height);
                txtMsg.Location = new Point(newForm.Width / 2 - txtMsg.Width / 2 - 10, newForm.Height / 2 - 40);
                newForm.Controls.Add(btnOK);
                newForm.Controls.Remove(btnCancel);
                btnOK.Text = "OK";
                btnOK.Location = new Point(newForm.Width / 2 - btnOK.Width / 2 -10, txtMsg.Location.Y + txtMsg.Height + 20);
                btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                newForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                return newForm.ShowDialog();
            }              
        }   

        public DialogResult Text(string title, string text, MessageBoxButtons type)
        {
            return spawnForm(title, text, type);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is create your own custom form. All forms inherit for System.Windows.Forms.Form. When you want to show the form call ShowDialog() which returns a DialogResult when the form is closed. Depending on what you click on the message box you set the internal DialogResult property and call Close().

CustomMessageBox class

```
public partial class CustomMessageBox : Form
{
    public CustomMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some other logic for OK button
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some other logic for Cancel button
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

To use the message box it would just be

```
CustomMessageBox customMessage = new CustomMessageBox();
DialogResult result = customMessage.ShowDialog();
```

Of course you would have to add more to show an actual message and you could make a show method that is static like MessageBox.Show() but this is the basics for the DialogResult part.